# Why does my debugger pause ("Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap") SOME times in this piece of code?

Tags: c++, debugging, pointers, runtime-error, codeblocks

I am writing an UNO game in C++ for educational purposes. I have been annoyed by this question for the past two days. I searched everywhere for an answer but nothing seems to be working. My debugger in Codeblocks 13.12 stops while I have these lines of code:

```
cout << "\nThe " << (*pla)->name << " takes 4 cards! " << endl;
for (int g=0; g<2; g++) take_two_cards(pla, deck);
```

The function `take_two_cards` of the class is the following:

```
void Hand::take_two_cards(Hand ** pla, Deck * deck)
{
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        (*pla)->draw_a_card(deck->remove_card());
    }
    return;
}
```

The function `remove_card` is the following:

```
Card * Deck::remove_card()
{
    Card * temp;
    vector<Card>::iterator v = vec.end()-1;
    temp=&(*v);
    vec.pop_back();
    return temp;
}
```

As you can figure out, in the Deck class I have a `vector` named vec.

And the function `draw_a_card` is the following:

```
void Hand::draw_a_card(Card * temp)
{
    vec.push_back(*temp);
    return;
}
```

The problem is exactly before the last `vec.push_back(*temp);` which I mentioned. I must add here that `take_two_cards` is used 2 times in a row. So `vec.push_back(*temp)` is actually called 4 times: 2 times that are presented here, and the whole process is repeated once more. While `vec.push_back(*temp)` works 3 times, the debugger pauses during the 4th time and I get

```
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
In ?? () ()
#7  0x0042b9ec in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Card>::deallocate (this=0x28fec4, __p=0x702c10)
at c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:110
```

Now, the 110th line of `new_allocator.h`

is this:

```
108:  void
109:  deallocate(pointer __p, size_type)
110:  { ::operator delete(__p); }
111:
112:  size_type
113:  max_size() const _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
114:  { return size_t(-1) / sizeof(_Tp); }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Reduce or eliminate all of the pointer crap, and you will be a happy person.  Retrieving pointers from items in a vector, and at the same time, adding items to that vector can invalidate those pointers you're holding on to.

Comment: So, do you suggest I make some function calls receive the actual variables as parameters rather than their references? And why does the debugger pause some times and not all the times?

Comment: If you have memory / pointer related issues, your program's behavior becomes undefined.  You should attempt to remove all pointers from your program, and use objects instead.  Only if there is a good reason to use pointers should you be using them.

Comment: Oh nice! I will try to remove all the pointers from this section of the code for starters, to see if the debugger continues.

Comment: If `Card` has correct copy semantics (you can copy `Card` objects with no issues), you can just return the object, since a copy is being created.  If only it becomes obvious that returning an object is not an option should you start using pointers.

Comment: Also, things like `Hand**` suggest you have something that represents a 2 dimensional array.  Instead, `std::vector<std::vector<Hand>>` can replace this (if `Hand` has correct copy semantics).

Comment: The funny thing is that I do not remember why I put Hand** instead of Hand*. I mean, I don't want an array of objects of Hand...

Comment: Now, I removed the pointers (at least in this section) and the problem continues in the exact same line as before. Is there any possibility that pointers aren't the issue here? I don't love pointers to defend them so much, but I am trying to find the issue.

Comment: Misuse of pointers and dynamically allocated memory is a cause for faults that point to runtime deallocation functions.  The code you posted only shows where the program finally breaks down.  If you posted a [mcve], then you will get more help.  In addition -- `vector<Card>::iterator v = vec.end()-1`  You don't check if the vector is empty -- if it is, this is a cause for error.